# How do I redirect according to the roles and presence of WooCommerce user registration?

Tags: woocommerce

I need to make several conditions for a redirect:

1. The user buys a subscription. Adds it to the cart and wants to place an order. If the user is registered, then he makes out an order. If the user is unregistered, he is offered registration, completing a short questionnaire when editing an account and back to the order checkout page.

If this is difficult to do, one can redirect the user to the account edit page after the order is completed.

[Illustration of the desired actions of the user.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7XBB.jpg)

2. An unregistered user buys products of a certain category (taking into account the category ID), wants to place an order. First, the user is redirected to the registration, and from there, back to the order checkout page.

If the user buys a subscription, automatically give it the "Subscriber" role, otherwise leave the default role of "Customer". I have a code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'woo_change_role_on_purchase' );

function woo_change_role_on_purchase( $order_id ) {

// get order object and items
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items();

$product_id = 222; // that's a specific product ID

foreach ( $items as $item ) {

    if( $product_id == $item['product_id'] && $order->user_id ) {
        $user = new WP_User( $order->user_id );

        // Remove role
        $user->remove_role( 'customer' ); 

        // Add role
        $user->add_role( 'subscriber' );
    }

}

}
```

I found the code written by csehasib, here - [Woocommerce redirect after registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30336980/woocommerce-redirect-after-registration)

```
//Redirect users to custom URL based on their role after login
function wp_woo_custom_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {

// Get the first of all the roles assigned to the user
$role = $user->roles[0];
$dashboard = admin_url();
$myaccount = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'my-account' ) );

if( $role == 'administrator' ) {

//Redirect administrators to the dashboard
$admin_redirect = get_option('admin_redirect');
$redirect = $admin_redirect;
} elseif ( $role == 'shop-manager' ) {

//Redirect shop managers to the dashboard
$shop_manager_redirect = get_option('shop_manager_redirect');
$redirect = $shop_manager_redirect;
} elseif ( $role == 'customer' || $role == 'subscriber' ) {

//Redirect customers and subscribers to the "My Account" page
$customer_redirect = get_option('customer_redirect');
$redirect = $customer_redirect;
} else {

//Redirect any other role to the previous visited page or, if not available, to the home
$redirect = wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : home_url();
}
return $redirect;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wp_woo_custom_redirect', 10, 2 );
```

and such code, written by LoicTheAztec:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'custom_redirection_after_registration', 10, 1 );
function custom_redirection_after_registration( $redirection_url ){
// Change the redirection Url
$redirection_url = get_home_url(); // Home page

return $redirection_url; // Always return something
}
```

But I can not write redirects, given the roles of users and the presence of registration.

**UPD**: An unregistered user buys a product from a certain category (take into account the ID), adds it to the cart and goes to the order processing. If it is registered, it makes out an order. If not, redirecting it for registration and back for ordering.

After making an order, if user bought a product of a certain category, redirecting it to the custom page "Thank You", or immediately to the edit page of the account "edit-account" in the personal account.

In principle, for an unregistered user, it is possible to enable the automatic creation of an account when buying products. It is necessary to add the condition of buying products from a certain category. And need to make a redirect after placing an order.

I shall be very glad to your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a plugin without the need for any code. Take a look at [Restrict Content](https://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-content/). If you need more than the basic features they have a pro version as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I do not need to restrict access and make membership. I need only a redirect.

Comment: Its able to handle redirects based on user role as well you will see that option in the edit page/post option

Comment: Sorry, I do not need this plugin. It does not perform those functions that I need.